# Proper way of showing a NSWindow as sheet

Tags: cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller, nsnotification

Function `NSBeginAlertSheet(...)` has all the events I need to have especially the `didDismiss:` callback, but I really need to be able to do the same sheet action with any window I want, so I discovered this notification:

`NSWindowDidOrderOffScreenAndFinishAnimatingNotification`

Which is posted whenever a sheet is closed AND done with animations
now, my question is can I use that? Or is there a better way?

I use ARC and I load the windows from `.xib` using `NSWindowController`.

Overall what I need is to show a window as sheet and catch all events.

Comment: Looks like a case for custom protocols and delegation. It is easy, like pulling your nails out, the first time.

Comment: With protocols and delegation you can essentially add the methods you need to your custom class and assign a delegate to receive the messages and take the required action. It is an essential element of the Cocoa environment. Along with long self-documenting class names.

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with

```
- (void)beginSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet modalForWindow:(NSWindow *)docWindow modalDelegate:(id)modalDelegate didEndSelector:(SEL)didEndSelector contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo
```

This calls the optional `didEndSelector` which should look like this:

```
- (void)sheetDidEnd:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode contextInfo:(void *)contextInfo;
```

This is all in the [`NSApplication`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html) documentation. There are two methods for ending the sheet:

```
- (void)endSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet returnCode:(NSInteger)returnCode
- (void)endSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet
```

So you could just do whatever you wanted to right before calling `endSheet:` or you could in the `sheetDidEnd:` method.

**Edit:**

[Here](http://cl.ly/QYFi) is an example project showing that after calling `[window orderOut:self]` then animation is finished and you can do what you'd like.

Comment: I know these, but like I said those 2 methods will call the selector on when sheet is about to animate and go up, what I was looking for was get the event when it's done animating!!! try it you'll see.

Comment: dude I learned something today! I didn't know -endSheet:returnCode: was synchronous! thanks! it helped! +1

Comment: @Mack awesome I'm glad, that should be nicer than the lower level stuff as well

Comment: Whats wrong wit it? Well, it's deprecated since 10.10. Starting with 10.9 the correct way is to call `beginSheet:completionHandler:` on a `NSWindow`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSWindowDidEndSheetNotification` It is posted whenever a sheet is finished animating out.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with 10.9, the correct way is to call `beginSheet:completionHandler:` on a `NSWindow` object.

This method has the advantage, that the completion handler is a block, so it can keep all the objects alive that are required as long as the sheet is still displayed and once the sheet is done and the block has been executed, the block itself is released and thus all objects it was keeping alive are as well.

To make sure a block keeps objects alive, use the objects within that block or if there is no way to use them in a meaningful fashion, put all of them into a `NSMutableArray` and within the block call `removeAllObjects` on that array; this requires the block to keep the array alive and the array keeps the rest alive -> memory management made easy.